# Find Percentage using Method in Java LinkedList

Tags: java, methods

I want to find percentage using the method that I have created from the class. But when I call the method in the application class, the output become 0 and not calculated. The expected output from my problem is the percentage of the infected people.
This is what I have try so far.

```
Pandemic p=pandemicList.getFirst();  //in application class      
        while(p!=null)
        {   String country=p.getCountry();
            int population=p.getPopulation();           
            if (country.charAt(0)=='M'||country.charAt(0)=='m')
            {   if(population>=1000000 && population<=1500000)
                {   System.out.println(p.toString());                    
                    System.out.println("The percentage infected: "+p.percentageInfected());
                    
                }
            }
            p=pandemicList.getNext();            
        }

public int percentageInfected() //in method class
    {   int percentage;
        percentage=infected/population*100;
        return percentage;
    }
```

Comment: I see there are 3 conditions, could you please put some debugger point, and check it out?  If one of the conditions not satisfied, the control will not go inside the scope then ```percentageInfected()``` would  not called.

Comment: Multiply by `100` *before* dividing by `population`. Say you have 12 infected in a population of 50, so you'd expect the result to be 24%. However, the `int` result of `12/50` is `0`, so `0*100` is also `0`. If you instead write `infected*100/population`, you get intermediate result `12*100 = 1200` and result `1200/50 = 24`.